# move AccessDataSource to code behind in vb

Tags: vb.net, aspxgridview

Looking to convert dozens of pages from aspx AccessDataSource to vb.net code behind. I'm using OleDB and ADO on other pages. wanted to know if there is any canned code to bind a simple select statement to the GridView1

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" 
    BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" ForeColor="Black" 
    GridLines="Vertical" AllowSorting="True">
    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="RowLevelCheckBox" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="UsersDataTbl.LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" SortExpression="LastName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="UsersDataTbl.FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="FirstName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="UsersDataTbl.Affiliation" HeaderText="Affiliation" SortExpression="Affiliation" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="UsersDataTbl.UID" HeaderText="UID" SortExpression="UID" />
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#6699CC" />
</asp:GridView>


<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" 
DataFile="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AccessSubSiteString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT [UsersDataTbl.LastName], [UsersDataTbl.FirstName], [UsersDataTbl.Affiliation], [UsersDataTbl.UID], [ALSProviders.ALS] 
    FROM [UsersDataTbl] LEFT JOIN [ALSProviders] ON (UsersDataTbl.UID = ALSProviders.UID) WHERE [UsersDataTbl.Career] = True 
    AND [UsersDataTbl.Active] = True AND ([UsersDataTbl.UID] NOT IN (SELECT UID FROM [ALSProviders]))
    ORDER BY [UsersDataTbl.LastName]" >
    <SelectParameters>         
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:AccessDataSource>
```

Comment: doesn't each of these files have an equivalent designer file that would have the code?

Comment: That’s what I’m asking?

Comment: then you already have that code...its in your project...look at the designer code behind

Comment: There is no code behind. I’m looking to get code behind equivalent of the AccessFataSource